# Using Wordpress functions in a custom php file

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a php file called scripts.php in the /myscripts folder of my Wordpress website.
I need to call in the scripts.php file the function  wp_get_recent_posts() but obviously I'm getting this error:

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function wp_get_recent_posts()

How can I include wordpress functions of my website?

Comment: Where located is your myscripts folder ? Give us a tree plz

Answer (score 0):

To access wp functions  in custom php file,  you should call

```
 require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
```

at the start of your custom php file.